# Attempting to Submit HTML Form to Database Has Blank Output

Tags: php, html, mysql

**I am new to PHP and web development, and trying to create an HTML form that will submit data into MYSQL.**

Upon checking phpmyadmin after submission of the form, it shows that there has been a row submitted,
however the row is completely blank. I had a problem before this one, that instead of a blank row, it would be "1" submitting instead of the data inserted into the HTML form. Now, no data submits into the [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACjGp.png).

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
Include("connection.php");

// HTML Identification
$lname = isset($_POST['lastname']);
$fname = isset($_POST['firstname']);
$email = isset($_POST['email']);
$phone = isset($_POST['phonenum']);
$addr = isset($_POST['address']);
$city = isset($_POST['city']);
$state = isset($_POST['state']);
$zip = isset($_POST['zipcode']);

//Database Insertion

$sql= "INSERT INTO CustomerInfo (LastName, FirstName, Email, PhoneNum, Address, City, State, ZipCode)
VALUES ('$lname', '$fname', '$email', '$phone', '$addr', '$city', '$state', '$zip')";

// Insertion
$ds= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// - Insertion Confirmation

if($ds)
{
print 'Row Inserted!';
print ' Response Recorded!';
}

?>
```

The HTML Form:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title> GS Entry Form </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css@2/out/water.css" </link>
<style>
h1 {text-align: center;}
h2 {text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

        <h1>Customer Entry Form</h1>

        <h2>Please Input Contact Information</h2>

        <form action="database.php" method="POST">
                First Name:<br />
                <input type="text" name="firstname" />

                <br /><br />

                Last Name:<br />
                <input type="text" name="lastname" />

                <br /><br />

                Email:<br />
                <input type="text" name="email" />

                <br /><br />

                Phone Number:<br />
                <input type="text" name="phonenum"/>

                <br /><br />

                Address:<br />
                <input type="text" name="address"/>

                <br /><br />

                City:<br />
                <input type="text" name="city"/>

                <br /><br />

                State:<br />
                <input type="text" name="state"/>

                <br /><br />

                Zip Code:<br />

                <input type="text" name="zipcode"/>

                <br /><br />

                <button type="button" name= "submit" value= "submit" />

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, also, is the connection.php referenced:

```
<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create Connection
$conn= mysqli_connect("$servername:3306","$username","$password","$dbname");

// Check Connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
        die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
}

        else echo "Connection successful! "
?>
```

I don't think it has anything to do with the connection, but I figured I would post it to cover all the bases. The attached imgur picture is what my database has been looking like after submissions have been made.

I truly am not sure what to do now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you! -G

EDIT:

This is what my PHP code looks like after the changes suggested from @EinLinuus:

```
<?php
Include("connection.php");

// HTML Identification POST
if(isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
}else{

        die("Firstname is missing");
}
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
        $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
}else{
        die("Lastname is missing");
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
}else{
        die("Email is missing");
}

if(isset($_POST['phone'])) {
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
}else{
        die("Phone Number is missing");
}

if(isset($_POST['addr'])) {
        $addr = $_POST['addr'];
}else{
        die("Address is missing");
}

if(isset($_POST['city'])) {
        $city = $_POST['city'];
}else{
        die("City is missing");
}

if(isset($_POST['state'])) {
        $state = $_POST['state'];
}else{
        die("State is missing");
}

if(isset($_POST['zip'])) {
        $zip = $_POST['zip'];
}else{
        die("Zip Code is missing");
}

//Database Insertion
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$stmt= $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO CustomerInfo(FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNum, Address, City, State, ZipCode) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $fname, $lname, $email, $phone, $addr, $city, $state, $zip);
$stmt->execute();
// Insertion
$sql= mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);

// - Insertion Confirmation

if($ds)
{
print 'Row Inserted!';
print ' Response Recorded!';
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

My HTML remains the same, besides adding ID attributes to each variable to no effect. I appreciate the help!

Comment: What exactly do you think `isset()` returns?

Comment: It's also worth noting that this code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/328193).  "Escaping" user input is the wrong approach.  Whatever tutorial you're following, abandon it and find one that uses prepared statements with query parameters.  You'll also want to [enable error reporting for mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22662488/328193) so you don't miss any errors from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function returns if the variable is declared or not -> the return type is a **boolean**.

```php
$test = [
    "hello" => "world"
];
var_dump(isset($test["hello"])); // bool(true)
var_dump(isset($test["something"])); // bool(false)
```

You can use `isset` to check if the field exists in the `$_POST` variable, but don't save the result of the `isset` function to the database. If you do so, the boolean will be converted to a number (`true` => `1`, `false` => `0`) and this number gets stored in the database.

Example:

```php
if(isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
    die("lastnameis missing");
}
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
```

**Security**

This code is vulnerable to  [SQL Injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You should **never trust user input**. I'd recommend to use prepared statements here:

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CustomerInfo (LastName, FirstName, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)");
$stmt->execute([$lname, $fname]);
```

In the SQL statement, replace the actual values with `?`. Now you can execute the statement and pass the values to the `execute` function. In the example above, `$lname` will replace the first `?`, `$fname` the second, ...

Comment: After taking what you've said into consideration I have further worked on the code, only to find that now I am being returned the error upon Submit: "Phone Number is missing". I believe this is related to the error I received relating to an undefined array of 'phone', 'addr', and 'zip'. It may be a problem related to the isset function still, but I'm not sure. I will edit my original post to show my code after the changes. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I think that's because your fields are named different than the fields you're using in PHP: the phone number field is named `phonenum` in your HTML (`name="phonenum"`), but in PHP you're trying to get `$_POST["phone"]`. Change this to `$_POST["phonenum"]` and it should work. Same for address and zip.

Comment: Oh, jeez! That's what it was! Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. I'm trying to get more acquainted with coding, and your guidance certainly bolsters it.